# MySQL construct nested json from two tables

Tags: php, mysql

Quit struggling a while on this one.

In php I start with some users:

```
$uids = [1,2,3,4,5];
```

Then I create different possible week plannings:

```
$plannings = array
(
 1 => 
 array(
   'friday' => 'cook'
 ),
 2 => 
 array(
   'friday' => 'cook',
   'sunday' => 'play outside'
 ),
 3 => 
 array(
   'friday' => 'training',
   'sunday' => 'training'
 ),
 4 => 
 array(
   'friday' => 'meeting',
   'sunday' => 'brunch'
 ),
 5 => 
 array(
   'sunday' => 'rest'
 )
);
```

insert them in mysql:

```
foreach($plannings as $id => $details)
{
   INSERT INTO planning (id, data) VALUES ($id, json_encode($details));
}
```

after that, I assign randomly each user with different planning for the week

```
$week = [];
foreach($uids as $uid)
{
  $week [$uid] = rand(1,5) // which refers to the id of one of the plannings in the plannings array;
}
```

then I put that into another table saved as JSON

```
INSERT INTO week (data) VALUES (json_encode($week));
```

Now it comes, if I want to get the week planning into one array from the DB I can only come up with this dirty solution. for each user included in the week planning I make a new query to retrieve that specific planning

```
$week = SELECT data FROM week WHERE id = 1

$week = json_decode($week->data);
foreach($week as $uid => $planning_id)
{
 $planning = SELECT data FROM planning WHERE id = $planning_id
 $week[$uid] = json_decode($planning->data)
}
```

Now I am kind of silently hoping there could be a way doing this in one simple query using JOINS, JSON_EXTRACT, and other fancy methods in Mysql which I don't know of

Comment: `json_endcode` is a typo

Comment: thx pointing that out, should be json_encode... is merely pseudo code as I didn't insert the db wrapper class neither in order to keep this as readable as possible

Comment: What did you try using [JOIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/join.html)?  The documentation has lost of examples, which cover this too!

Comment: post a [mre] wwith all tables and data, also tell us exactly which mysql Mariadb version you have

Comment: Please share the expected result

Comment: @IndraKumarS the expected result is that the db spits out: {1: {"friday": "cook"}, 2: {"friday": "cook"}, 3: {"friday": "cook"}, 4: {"friday": "cook"},5: {"friday": "cook"}}. instead of {1: 1, 2: 1, 3: 1, 4: 1, 5:1}

Comment: You must create a db fiddle with table structures and sample data to help us help you back. And your expected output does not correlate with the plannings array ?

Comment: @IndraKumarS thx, I made it correlate. Ok i'll try recreating working code out of this. Hoped somebody would tell me this is easy to fix. I'll keep you all informed

Comment: @VermeerschWouter Check my answer

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your need correctly, You want to have an INNER JOIN ON values of a two different JSON from 2 different tables.

I assume you use MySQL 8+.

You requirement can be achieved by using [JSON_TABLE functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html)

> **JSON_TABLE(expr, path COLUMNS (column_list) [AS] alias)**
>
> Extracts data from a JSON document and returns it as a relational
> table having the specified columns.

Lets create tables with a sample data (based on your php codes)

```
CREATE TABLE `week` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `data` longtext NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO week (data) VALUES ('{"1":2,"2":1,"3":2,"4":1,"5":4}');

CREATE TABLE `planning` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
  `data` longtext DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

INSERT INTO planning (id, data) VALUES (1, '{"friday":"cook"}') ;
INSERT INTO planning (id, data) VALUES (2, '{"friday":"cook","sunday":"play outside"}') ;
INSERT INTO planning (id, data) VALUES (3, '{"friday":"training","sunday":"training"}') ;
INSERT INTO planning (id, data) VALUES (4, '{"friday":"meeting","sunday":"brunch"}') ;
INSERT INTO planning (id, data) VALUES (5, '{"sunday":"rest"}') ;
```

`SELECT * FROM week` will return

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"1":2,"2":1,"3":2,"4":1,"5":4} |

And `SELECT * FROM planning` will return

| id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"friday":"cook"} |
| 2 | {"friday":"cook","sunday":"play outside"} |
| 3 | {"friday":"training","sunday":"training"} |
| 4 | {"friday":"meeting","sunday":"brunch"} |
| 5 | {"sunday":"rest"} |

Now you want to have `INNER JOIN on week.data.json_field's_value = planning.id`

```
SELECT
    mytable.*,
    planning.data
FROM
    WEEK,
    JSON_TABLE(
        JSON_EXTRACT(WEEK.data, '$.*'),
        "$[*]" COLUMNS(plan_id INT PATH "$")
    ) mytable
INNER JOIN planning ON mytable.plan_id = planning.id
```

Result will be

| plan_id | data |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | {"friday":"cook","sunday":"play outside"} |
| 1 | {"friday":"cook"} |
| 2 | {"friday":"cook","sunday":"play outside"} |
| 1 | {"friday":"cook"} |
| 4 | {"friday":"meeting","sunday":"brunch"} |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=92edc107583d62e311df89c1c77e7491)*

Comment: Heckin nice answer. I didn't know about JSON_TABLE. Super cool!

Comment: That's great my friend! how would that translate to MySQL 5.7 ? Now it throws me the following error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(
        JSON_EXTRACT(week.data, '$.*'),
         "$[*]"
         COLUMNS(
    ' at line 5

Comment: I dont know how it can be done in MySQL 5.7

Comment: I see you use longtext instead of json type for the data col, is there a specific reason why you use the one over the other? I'll dig a little deeper on how fixing the error and make it work on Mysql 5.7. anyway thank you a lot for pointing me into the right direction!

Comment: JSON is an alias for LONGTEXT

Comment: @IndraKumarS In MySQL, JSON is a real datatype; it converts to a binary representation that's optimized for searching. In MariaDB it's an alias for LONGTEXT.

Comment: @VermeerschWouter `JSON_TABLE()` was added in MySQL 8.x. You can't do this in MySQL 5.7.  You'll need to loop through the JSON array in PHP after decoding it.

Comment: @barmar yes but when using with 100+ users for 10+ weeks this would result into 1000 db select queries  so In order to make it as efficient as possible I first select all plannings convert it to an array holding as key the planning id and value the json encoded string. While looping over the users in the week I json_decode the needed plannings. This results in 11 queries from which the planning query result can hold +1000 results. Hope this is not that much heavier then the method for MySQL pointed out in this answer

Comment: @VermeerschWouter Maybe you should rethink using the JSON type, and normalize your schema.

Comment: @Barmar It was once like that, wchich resulted in so much rows within the many to many relational table

Comment: That's normal for relational databases.

Comment: RDBMS systems came into existence in the early 1970. I think the addition of some horizontal scaling to a system which survived so long can make it survive even longer